# cloudformation template to update with new nonkeyattributes to GSI in dynamodb resource without removing GSI and adding it back again

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I want to update GSI with new nonkeyattributes to existing ones through cloudformation. Currently when I want to add new nonkeyattributes I need to deprovision GSI and provision it back with new and existing nonkeyattributes. Is there a way to add nonkeyattributes without deprovision GSI everytime ?

Resources:

DynamoDBTable:

```
Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
Properties:
  TableName: "employee table"
  AttributeDefinitions:
    - AttributeName: "CustomerId"
      AttributeType: "S"
    - AttributeName: "empId"
      AttributeType: "S"
    - AttributeName: "Date"
      AttributeType: "N"
  KeySchema:
    - AttributeName: "CustomerId"
      KeyType: "HASH"
  ProvisionedThroughput:
    ReadCapacityUnits: 20
    WriteCapacityUnits: 20
  GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
    - IndexName: "ByempId"
      KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: "empId"
        KeyType: "HASH"
      - AttributeName: "Date"
        KeyType: "RANGE"
      Projection:
        NonKeyAttributes:
          - "status1"
          - "status2"
          - "status3"
        ProjectionType: INCLUDE
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: "20"
        WriteCapacityUnits: "20"
```

If I want to add new NonKeyAttributes status4 I need to comment out lines from GlobalSecondaryIndexes to end of the template and provision with all NonKeyAttributes (status1,2,3,4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updates to GSI are **not supported** as explained in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html#cfn-dynamodb-table-globalsecondaryindexes):

> **Updates are not supported**. The following are exceptions:

> If you update only the provisioned throughput values of global secondary indexes, you can update the table without interruption.

> You can delete or add one global secondary index without interruption. If you do both in the same update (for example, by changing the index's logical ID), the update fails.

As you can see, **you can delete and create new GSI**, but not updated existing one.